# Rehashing generated MD5 Code in Java

Tags: java, hashcode

Unfortunately, I am not good at writing java code and I need your help to be able to come up with a proper solution. I was asked to write an application doing the followings;

The application must find whether there are any collisions if a certain data is rehashed, given number of times. (default is 1000 times, but be prepared to increase it).
The application must take a text data(data, i.e. password) as input.
The application must take a number (number of times to rehash) ad input.
The application must output the hashes which occured more than once.
!!!Speed is important.

According to requirement I have found a piece of code generating the hashcode of a given text but I am not able to implement it based on the application I was asked to write. Anybody can help me to do this please?

Here is the code I have found;

```
public String MD5(String md5) {
       try {
            java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] array = md.digest(md5.getBytes());
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
              sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
           }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the code I have written but seems it doesn't work. Obviously, I am doing something wrong. Is there anybody who can tell me the wrong part of the code? Any help is very much appreciated.

```
private void jButtonrehashingMousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {

    String input = jTextAreaRehashing.getText();
    List<String> hashes = new ArrayList<String>();
    hashes.add(MD5(input));

    for (int i = 0; i <= (int) jComboBoxNumberOfHash.getSelectedItem(); i++)
    {
        input = hashes.get(i);
        hashes.add(MD5(input));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= hashes.size(); j++)
    {
        for (int k = j +1; k < hashes.size(); k++)
        {
            if (hashes.get(j).equals(hashes.get(k)))
            {
                jTextAreaRehashing.setText(jTextAreaRehashing.getText() + 
                        "Hash occured more than once: " + hashes.get(j) + "\n\r");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: We are not a code writing factory. Try something. If a particular part doesn't work, and you provide as many details as possible as to why, we will help you

Comment: Hello dear Sotirios. I totally agree with you and please find my updated question as above. thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: I realized that I am not getting the text as an input from 'String input = jTextAreaRehashing.getText();' and fix it by replacing 'String input = jTextFieldHasCodeInput.getText();' but the result is the same. The application is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not producing any output because it's not finding any duplicates because there aren't any duplicates.
I think your code is working.

The chances of an MD5 clash (the hash being repeated) are incredibly low, so 1,000 rehashes will almost never return anything.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

However to read a little further into your question, let’s assume we are taking over 10^20 or 2^64 rehashes, then we might start to see some clashes.

MD5 has a 128-bit digest size, in other words, there are 2^128 possible different MD5 hashes to process.

(I do not know how large the set would need to be, in my couple of trials I didn't find any.)

Now that we are using such large sets of data, this is where the efficiency (speed) becomes important.
May I suggest HashSet rather than ArrayLists.
Also consider using the aHashSet.contains(Object a) to test rather than the double for loop.

[Java collection insertion: Set vs. List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044228/java-collection-insertion-set-vs-list)

[Fastest way to check if a List<String> contains a unique String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307549/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-liststring-contains-a-unique-string)

I would also do the checking for duplicates higher up in your algorithm

```
private void jButtonrehashingMousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {

String input = jTextAreaRehashing.getText();
List<String> hashes = new ArrayList<String>();
hashes.add(MD5(input));

for (int i = 0; i <= (int) jComboBoxNumberOfHash.getSelectedItem(); i++)
{
    input = hashes.get(i);
    output = MD5(input)
    if(hashes.contains(output)){
      jTextAreaRehashing.setText(jTextAreaRehashing.getText() + 
                    "Hash occured more than once: " + output + "\n\r");
    }
    hashes.add(output);
}
```

}

Good Luck.